# Not able to come out of prevent default

Tags: jquery

```
$('#save').click(function(e){
    //alert('hi');
    e.preventDefault();     
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"/customerdetails/" + $('#company_name').val().replace(/ /g,'_')  + "/",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'customer':$('#company_name').val()},
        success: function(data){
            //alert($('#company_name').val());  
            //alert('f');
            //alert(data.tag);
            if(data.tag){
                alert("Company with the same name already exists.");
                $('#company_name').val('');  
                return true;
            }
        }
        //return false;
    });//end of submit
    //return false;
});
```

Im using the above code, but whatever i'm trying to come out of prevent default but not working. Please help me

Comment: Can you please explain more about your question?

Comment: I'm trying to use prevent default in my ajax post but after doing the things i'm not able to click button, basically the button is stuck in prevent default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you need, but ... I'll give it a shot ...

Remove `e.preventDefault();`

Change `return true;` to `return false;` or remove it.

Remove the comment on `//return false;`

Change the event from `click` to `submit`

Final code will be something like this

```
$('FORM ID').on('submit', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/customerdetails/" + $('#company_name').val().replace(/ /g,'_')  + "/",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'customer':$('#company_name').val()},
        success: 
            function(data) {
                     if(data.tag) {
                        alert("Company with the same name already exists.");
                        $('#company_name').val('');  
                        // return false;
                     }
                }
            });
        return false;
});
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that we are using the wrong event. I edited my answer. See if it works, now ...

Answer (score 0):

After preventing the default action you need to manually redirect the user, since you have removed the default event handler from the element.

```
$('#save').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/customerdetails/" + $('#company_name').val().replace(/ /g,'_')  + "/",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'customer':$('#company_name').val()},
        success: 
            function(data) {
                     if(data.tag) {
                        alert("Company with the same name already exists.");
                        $('#company_name').val('');  
                        // return false;
                     }
                     else {
                        // do something here
                        window.location = "http://www.example.com"
                     }
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: As @felipe-miosso said you should also hook onto the form submit action.